# Creating a human-readable list from the values of a map

Tags: java

I'm creating a human-readable list from the keys of a `map` object.  I want it to be comma-separated, but include the word "and" at the end before the last element, supplying a given locale for the word "and".

E.g., my map might have the strings:

```
"AK", "Alaska"
"CA", "California"
"NY", "New York"
```

I would want as output:

```
Alaska, California, and New York
```

for English and

```
Alaska, California, y New York
```

for Spanish.

So I have:

```
public static String getHumanReadableStates(Map<String, String> stateMap) {

    long count = stateMap.values().stream().map(Object::toString).count();
    return stateMap.values().stream().map(Object::toString)
            .limit(count - 1)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
            .concat(", ")
            .concat(LocaleUtil.getBundleValue("theWordAnd"))
            .concat(" ")
            .concat(Objects.requireNonNull(stateMap.values().stream().reduce((first, second) -> second)
                    .orElse(null)));
}
```

where `LocaleUtil` has a method called `getBundleValue()` to simply get the word "and" from `messages.properties`.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?  Or should streams be avoided altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stream-based approach is still feasible, by materializing your state names into a `List` first.

By using a `List`, you can retrieve all the names *except* the last using [`List.subList(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) (this may be empty, for a single-entry `Map`), and then retrieving the last (or the only, for a single-entry `Map`) directly using a simple `List.get(int)`. Afterwards, you just need to handle for an empty `Map` or `String` values.

```
public static String getHumanReadableStates(Map<String, String> stateMap) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>(stateMap.values());
    if (names.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    String exceptLastPlusBlank = Stream.concat(
            names.subList(0, names.size() - 1).stream(), Stream.of(""))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    return Stream.of(exceptLastPlusBlank, names.get(names.size() - 1))
            .filter(v -> !v.isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(LocaleUtil.getBundleValue("theWordAnd") + " "));
}
```

`Stream.of("")` is introduced to append the final comma.

Answer (score 1):

To get the different behaviour for the final element, you will need to be able to tell how many items are left in the list *before* you hit the end, so that seems to rule out streams, since you only have access to one element at a time, and the "built in" `joining` collector doesn't appear to allow any special treatment for the final element.

So really, you're reduced to `StringBuilder` and the logic (pseudocode):

- if (have any elements at all)

  - add first element to string
  - while (have more than one element remaining)
  - add delimiter (", " I guess), then the next element from the list
  - add " and " (or translation), then the final element from the list

Or, for slightly more readable code [citation needed], still using streams a bit, take the list of values, and:

- if (have any elements at all)

  - remove final element and keep safe somewhere
  - if (any elements remaining)
  - apply `.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))` to list
  - concatenate with " and " (or translation) and the saved final element, then return it
  - else, just return the saved final element